# Set intersection problem.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $ A \cap B' = A - B$ where $A \cup B$ is the universal set? 
I am an absolute beginner at Sets, So please dont vote down my question because it might  be too easy for you. $ B'$ refers to the complement of set $B$.

Comment: You are correct, assuming that $B'$ denotes the complement of $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn’t matter whether $A\cup B$ is the universal set or not. If $x\in A\cap B\,'$, then by definition $x\in A$ and $x\in B\,'$, so $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$. But that means by definition that $x\in A\setminus B$. This shows that $A\cap B\,'\subseteq A\setminus B$.

Conversely, if $x\in A\setminus B$, then $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, so $x\in A$ and $x\in B\,'$, and therefore $x\in A\cap B\,'$. This shows that $A\setminus B\subseteq A\cap B\,'$. Put the two together, and you have $A\cap B\,'=A\setminus B$.

Both simply describe the set of things that are in $A$ but not in $B$.